# Error propagation of the logarithmic mean of two variables

Tags: logarithms, means, error-propagation

My problem is fairly simple to explain:
I am calculating the logarithmic mean, $M_{lm}$ of two variables, $x$ and $y$, both associated with an error, $\sigma x$ and $\sigma y$, and need to propagate the corresponding error.

$x = 3977$, $\sigma x = \pm 397$

$y = 3788$, $\sigma y = \pm 381$

$M_{lm} = \frac{x-y}{\ln x-\ln y} = 3882$

In an attempt to derive the error propagation equation, I split the logmean equation into two parts, (a) the numerator and (b) the denominator, and propagated their errors separately:

$(a) = x-y$

$(b) = \ln x-\ln y$

$\sigma (a) = \sqrt{\sigma x^2+\sigma y^2}$

$\sigma (b) = \sqrt{(\frac{\sigma x}{x})^2+(\frac{\sigma x}{x})^2}$

The error of $M_{lm}$ would then be calculated as follows:

$\sigma M_{lm} = M_{lm}\sqrt{\left(\frac{\sqrt{\sigma x^2+\sigma y^2}}{x-y}\right)^2-\left(\frac{\sqrt{(\frac{\sigma x}{x})^2+(\frac{\sigma x}{x})^2}}{\ln x-\ln y}\right)^2} = 15981$

Since this error seemed to be far too large, I used several online tools/Matlab scripts/Wolfram Alpha to calculate the error actual error all of which returning the same error of $\sigma M_{lm} = 275$.

This is the equation Wolfram Alpha uses:

$\sigma M_{lm} = \sqrt{\frac{\sigma x^2 y^2 (x \ln y + x + x (-\ln x) - y)^2 + \sigma y^2 x^2 (-y \ln x + x - y + y \ln y)^2}{x^2 y^2 (\ln x - \ln y)^4}}$

I have tried to derive this equation all day but can't seem to get there.
Any help would be kindly appreciated!

Cheers Jake

Comment: You get the error as $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{x-y}{\ln(x)-\ln(y)} \sigma_x \oplus \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \frac{x-y}{\ln(x)-\ln(y)} \sigma_y$ where $q \oplus r = \sqrt{q^2+r^2}$ and the derivatives are evaluated at the "predictor" point (here $(x,y)=(3977,3788)$). This really only works properly when the uncertainties are very small relative to the predicted values, which isn't entirely correct here, but presumably this is what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Ian! Is there a more accurate way to calculate the error or would you say this is the best approach I can get?

Comment: The more accurate way that takes into account the comparatively large errors of the individual components is to compute the actual variance of $F(X,Y)$ when $(X,Y)$ are independent Gaussians with the specified means and standard deviations. In the limit where the ratios of the standard deviations to means all go to zero, this reduces to what I said above.

Comment: Thanks again, Ian!

Comment: Note that what I said has some additional subtlety when dealing with functions with non-integrable singularities, for example 1/X where X is normally distributed with mean $10^4$ and standard deviation 1 is reasonably treated as normally distributed with mean $10^{-4}$ and standard deviation $10^{-8}$ even though actually this variable doesn't even have finite expectation.